# Distribute a database made with JavaDB with Java program

Tags: java, javadb

I'm creating a program in Java in which I have to use a lot of tables.
I made the decision to create all those tables in a JavaDB file.

However, now I want to distribute this filled JavaDB file with my JAR file
for distribution, since connecting to a server is not an option.

In the past I could only distribute an empty database with the JAR
by using that Derby package.

Any ideas?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question but it is possible to package a read-only database inside a JAR. From the derby documentation:

> #### [Accessing Databases-in-a-Jar in the Class Path](http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/develop/develop38.html#Accessing+Databases-in-a-Jar+in+the+Class+Path)
>
> Once an archive containing one or more
>   Derby databases has been created it
>   can be placed in the class path. This
>   allows access to a database from
>   within an application without the
>   application's knowing the path of the
>   archive. When jar or zip files are
>   part of the class path, you do not
>   have to specify the jar subsubprotocol
>   to connect to them.
>
> To access a database in a zip or jar
>   file in the class path:
>
> 1. Set the class path to include the jar or zip file before starting up
>      Derby:
>
>    ```
>    CLASSPATH="C:\dbs.jar;%CLASSPATH%"
>    ```
> 2. Connect to a database within the jar or zip file with one of the
>      following connection URLs:
>
>    ```
>    jdbc:derby:/databasePathWithinArchive
>
>    (standard syntax)
>
>    jdbc:derby:classpath:/databasePathWithinArchive
>
>    (syntax with subsubprotocol)
>    ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> jdbc:derby:/products/boiledfood
> jdbc:derby:classpath:/products/boiledfood
> ```

If this doesn't answer the question, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I think i'm a beginner at this..

Where do I place the Database file in the JAR?

and what is a subprotocol / classpath?

Thanks for helping!
Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Paintrick: 1. The `databasePathWithinArchive` is relative path to root of classpath elements. 2. the subprotocol is this part: `jdbc:derby:[subprotocol]`