# How to provide java application with database?

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I have a database-driven application (Apache Derby). I connect to the database by a URL:

```
jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/kcal_calc_db
```

My database was created via NetBeans, and is in the '.netbeans-derby' folder. How can I include this database with my JAR/EXE file?

Comment: look abt in-memory database like h2.It can help u.

Comment: You can't include it in executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this related question: [Distribute a database made with JavaDB with Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316315/distribute-a-database-made-with-javadb-with-java-program)

Note that you'll want your database to be accessed as an Embedded database, not a Client-Server database, so you'll need to change your Connection URL, use the Embedded JDBC driver, package derby.jar into your application, etc.